# Empty the file contents or truncate file in python

Tags: python

I am opening a file called `test.txt` with the file object say `file1`.
Without closing the previously opened file, I am opening same file `test.txt` with file object say `file2` and trying to empty the file contents with `file.truncate(0)`.

I can see my file contents are not getting deleted.
Is there any way I can fix this?

```py
import os
def _write(_file):
        _file.write("Hello World")

file1=open("test.txt",'a')

_write(file1)

file2=open("test.txt",'a')
file2.truncate(0)
```

I want delete the file contents without using same file object `file1` because the the code which deletes the file contents is in different file.

Comment: opening an already opened file will create an ambiguous situation.

When the program ends, both the buffers will try to flush and close the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `with` in order to close file after the process done.

```
with open("test.txt",'a') as file1:
    _write(file1)

with open("test.txt",'a') as file2:
    file2.truncate(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to empty a file is opening it in *writing* mode. You can close it right after:

```py
open('test.txt', 'w').close()
```